# cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

I'm new to ruby. I removed ruby 1.9 with `sudo apt-get purge ruby` and then
I installed ruby 2.3.0 using [ruby-install](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#ruby-install). But I got the following error

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:4:in `<internal:gem_prelude>
```

when running `rspec my_script.rb`.

Still can't fix this after googling! Anyone can help me out?

Comment: did you install the gem `rspec` with the new ruby version (2.3.0) or it's already installed ?

Comment: @AbdooDev It's already installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the rspec binary was only installed for your previous ruby version. Therefore it is found, but not guaranteed to work.

I'd recommend to use something like `rvm` (https://rvm.io/) or `rbenv` (https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). Both of them can easily handle different ruby versions while maintaining dependencies (e.g. different load paths, different gem versions, etc.). I'd even use `rvm` if there is only one single ruby version installed on a system.